# ES6 equivalent to lodash _.clone (lodash failing to clone ES6 Proxy)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, underscore.js, lodash

I'm refactoring some code to take advantage of some ES6 features.  One thing I encountered was issues with lodash and applying _.clone to a es6 proxy.  I was wondering if there is an es6 equivalent to the clone method supplied by lodash. My searching has not turned up any results.

thx.

Comment: Looks like the answer is "Object.assign".

Comment: Be aware though that `Object.assign` does not do deep cloning.

Comment: Correct, it is a shallow copy like the _.clone method @sma

Comment: It depends very much on the proxy whether and how it can be cloned. Please show us some example code that is not working with lodash.

Comment: Also note that Object.assign only works for plain objects like {}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using ES6 Object.assign appears is a substitute for _.clone.

```
var obj = { a: 1 };
var copy = Object.assign({}, obj);
console.log(copy); // { a: 1 }
```

It also appears to successfully clone a ES6 proxy, for which lodash failed and returned an "undefined" .

Comment: For me, lodash (4.17.4) did not return `undefined`, but a clone of the proxied object. Still losing the proxy. And I need the deep clone (as the object contains objects as properties), so `Object.assign` wouldn't work for me.